# Action of conc H2SO4 on pinacol

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, alcohols

Question: Please suggest the correct answer along with suitable mechanism

[image: Please suggest the correct answer along with mechanism.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no effort in the question.

Comment: I guess dehydration can occur if heated though, so  can be (B).

Comment: Answer is A. But dont know why. B and C also seem correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would also say A.{PINNACOL PINNACOLON REARRANGEMENT)

First H+ can create carbocation at any one of the carbon and then methyl shift(CH3-)   from other carbon can occur and we would get positive charge on carbon attached directly with OH ,  and then OH can share its lone pair and form double  bond O.   So ketone on left and four degree carbon on right

What's the answer given? 
And pls also post the efforts you had made for the question in problem description :))